# Get cell index in excel

Tags: excel, indexing, coordinates, cell

How can I get the cell index from the row number and the column number?
Assuming having row=1 and column=3, I want to return A3 to use it in a MIN function later on.

Comment: But row #1, column #3 is cell **C1**

Comment: Yes my bad. I meant C1 not A3

Answer (score 1):

You could use two Excel functions to do that, like following:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(row_number;col_number))
```

`ADDRESS` gives you the cell address based on row & col number

`INDIRECT` gives you the value from given cell address

Example:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;3))
```

This gives you value from cell C1.